# Drag and Double Click conflicted in group

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In a small d3 code I have coded a circle which had one behavior on drag and another on double click:

```
var new_circ = circles
      .enter() // Add circle to svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "draggableCircle");

    new_circ.append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius*radius_buffer)
    .style('fill', 'transparent');

    new_circ.append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style('fill', 'black')
    .attr("class", "visiblecircle");


    svg.selectAll(".draggableCircle")
      .data(dataset) // update circles
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
           return "translate(" + xScale(d[0]) + "," + yScale(d[1]) + ")";
        })
      .on("click", function(d){d3.event.stopPropagation();}) // click callback
      .on("dblclick", mousedownCircle) // dblclick callback
      .call(drag)
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .moveToFront();
```

When I remove movetoFront(), double click and drag work. With movetoFront() only the drag works. The movetoFront is shown below:

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
};
```

Any ideas what happens?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `mousedownCircle` do and does it execute at all?

Comment: no, it doesn't execute at all. It should remove the circle.